# ¿Cómo puedo validar fechas c# en Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Buenas quisiera que me ayuden en esta validacion por favor no se que estoy haciendo mal pero no esta validando lo que estoy realizando, para ello estoy realizando con asp c#

Les explico estoy realizando un if que si en caso la fecha de emision es mayor a la fecha de un pago muestre un error pero no me logra mostrar ese mensaje.

Mi fecha de Emision es : 30/03/2017

Mi fecha de Pago es :22/03/2017

Ahi debe mostrar el Mensaje que estoy colocando

```
if (DateTime.Parse(txtFechaEmision.Text) > DateTime.Parse(TxtFechaPago.Text))
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("La Fecha de Emision Tiene que ser menor a a la Fecha Pago", "..::Aviso del Sistema::..");
                    }
```

Comment: La prueba la estas haciendo con las fechas que indicaste??? *(Emisión: 30/07/17 -- Pago: 22/04/17)*

Comment: Si esos son un ejemplo . pero las fechas pueden varias tanto en Fecha Emision y de Pago

Comment: Ahhh okei... porque según tu condición (que emisión sea mayor a pago) las fechas que colocaste como ejemplo estarían mal =/

Comment: asi es la condicion un ejemplo :

Cuando realiza un pago de luz o agua primero es lo que viene es tu fecha de emision si tu ejemplo te viene un 30/03/2017 tu no puedes pagar un 25/03/2017 porque primero te tiene que venir una fecha un recibo

Comment: Sí obvio, pero en este caso y siguiendo tu ejemplo.. pusiste que la fecha de emisión es el 30 de marzo y que el pago es el 22 de abril... entonces es válido.. pero en fin.. es un detalle... acabo de probar tú codigo y me funciono perfecto. Le realizaste un debug a las fechas que estas recibiendo? Quizás no vienen en el formato correcto...

Comment: lo probaste con mi codigo ? yo esos texbox lo agarro de un sql server pero si tienen valor o me podrias colocar tu respuesta para probarlo y si esta correcto le doy que esta bien check @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Amigo solamente reemplace los parámetros del *parse* por un string... yo empezaría probando con datos en duro en el *parse (DateTime.parse("30/03/2017"))*; si te funciona, es porque los datos que recibes de SQL están en un formato que no corresponde...

Comment: @Pierro, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar con que valores no logra ingresar a tu `if` por que con los valores que indicas nunca entraría a dicha condición (según tú son de ejemplos). También, indica si es para `Windows Form` o `Asp.net Web Forms` (revisa el código que estás poniendo con la etiqueta que utilizas y el título).

Comment: @Davlio Muchas Gracias amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el código intenta realizar el parse directamente dentro de la condicion.

En el dado caso que el servidor este configurado en otro idioma diferente a español de México el parse no funcionara como debe y obtendras resultados extraños.

Para hacer la comparación a prueba de la configuración del servidor es mejor realizar un DateTime.TryParse y valores por default.

También para evitar que un cambio en el servidor afecte la comparación de fechas es mejor agregar la cultura y estilos para forzar el formato que necesitas.

Adjunto un ejemplo que puedes usar para resolver el problema.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var date1 = "30/03/2017";
        var date2 = "22/03/2017";

        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt2 = dt1;
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX");
        var styles = DateTimeStyles.None;


        bool fechaValida = DateTime.TryParse(date1, culture, styles, out dt1) 
                           && DateTime.TryParse(date2, culture, styles, out dt2);

        Console.WriteLine(dt1 >= dt2);

        if (!fechaValida){
            Console.WriteLine("Error en la fecha");
        }

        if (dt1 >= dt2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("La Fecha de Emision Tiene que ser menor a a la Fecha Pago ..::Aviso del Sistema::..");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando comparas valores siempre es mejor utilizar los métodos de comparación que trae el lenguaje que utilizas. En este caso concreto, `DateTime` trae un método [Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) que te devuelve -1, 0 o 1 en caso de que sea menor, igual o mayor. Eso si, solo compara fechas, así que tendrás que hacer antes un parseo para asegurarte que son fechas válidas.